# Can anyone help me? my app keeps stopping and i dunno why

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, calculator

```
abstract class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Parcelable {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main))

    val a = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.editTextNumberDecimal)
    val b = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.editTextNumberDecimal2)
    val c = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.editTextNumberDecimal3)
    val e = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.editTextNumberDecimal4)
    val f = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.editTextNumberDecimal5)
    val g = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.editTextNumberDecimal6)
    val n = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.editTextNumberDecimal13)
    
    val h = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextNumberDecimal7)
    val i = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextNumberDecimal8)
    val j = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextNumberDecimal9)
    val k = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextNumberDecimal10)
    val l = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextNumberDecimal11)
    val m = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextNumberDecimal12)
    val o = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextNumberDecimal14)
    
    val bt = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)



    
    bt.setOnClickListener {
        
        val fm = a.text.toString().toFloat()
        val s = b.text.toString().toFloat()
        val kmod1 = c.text.toString().toFloat()
        val kmod2 = e.text.toString().toFloat()
        val d1 = f.text.toString().toFloat()
        val t = g.text.toString().toFloat()
        val n1 = n.text.toString().toFloat()

        
        val fk = (fm - (1.645 * s)).toFloat()
        val ftk = 1.3 * fk
        val fvk = 0.15 * fk
        val fck = 0.1 * fk
        val fmk = 1.1 * fk

        val kmod = (kmod1 * kmod2 * 0.8).toFloat()


        val fcd: Float = kmod * fk / 2
        h.setText(fcd.toString())

        val ftd = (kmod * ftk / 1.8).toFloat()
        i.setText(ftd.toString())

        val fvd = (kmod * fvk / 2).toFloat()
        j.setText(fvd.toString())

        val fcd1 = (kmod * fck / 2).toFloat()
        k.setText(fcd1.toString())

        val fmd = (kmod * fmk / 1.8).toFloat()
        l.setText(fmd.toString())

       
        val d = d1 - 2 * t
```

when I build the app it says that is Build Sucessfully but when I try to run it on the emulator, It keeps stopping.
the app is the calculator type It read some numbers as strings, turn them into floats numbers for it calculate and it writes the resulte as string again

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Is it intentional that you're missing a ```}```?

Comment: nop, but it was a ctrl C ctrl V missclick

Comment: Please post your xml file